Encountering a warning while running the Overleaf document, "Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec."
Following are the packages which I have used in the document.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

the document class is \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

Welcome. // I suggest to create a simple enough dummy document, which compiles when we copy it AND shows your problem. If needed, you may follow theses steps to arrive there: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

The llncs class redefines \vec1, unless the orivec is passed to it.
\documentclass[orivec,runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum}

I grouped the packages by “genre”. Not necessary, but helps document maintenance. If you use float for its [H] option to floats, don't: that option is a source of severe typographical problems, rather than a solution.
Footnote
1 The definition of \vec done in llncs is
\DeclareRobustCommand\vec[1]{\mathchoice{\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle#1$}}
{\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle#1$}}
{\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle#1$}}
{\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}

If one really wants to print vectors using bold math italic, it's much better to pass the orivec option, to do \usepackage{bm} after any font package and in the preamble do
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\vec}{m}{\bm{#1}}%
}

This for pdflatex. For usage with unicode-math the method would be different.
